# Python 3 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'features'

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm, cucumber, python-behave

Im getting a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'features' when I import a page object model from a step python file. Im using python 3 MacBook.

features/steps/tutorial.feature

```
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from behave import *


from features.lib.pages.login_page import LoginPage

use_step_matcher("re")


@given("user is lead to the login page")
def step_impl(context):
    """
    :type context: behave.runner.Context
    """
    context.browser.get("https://www.phptravels.net/login")


@when("I log in")
def step_impl(context):
    """
    :type context: behave.runner.Context
    """
    page = LoginPage(context)
    page.login()
```

features/lib/pages/login_page.py

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec


class LoginPage:
    locator_dictionary = {
        "email_field": (By.NAME, 'username'),
        "password_field": (By.ID, 'password'),
        "login_button": (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.btn.btn-action.btn-lg.btn-block.loginbtn'),
        "accept_cookies": (By.ID, 'cookyGotItBtn')
    }

    def __init__(self, context):
        self.browser = context.browser

    def login(self, username="xxxxx", passwd="xxxxx"):
        b = self.browser

        WebDriverWait(b, 10).until(
            ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "cookyGotItBtn"))).click()

        b.find_element_by_name('username').send_keys(username)
        b.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys(passwd)
        b.find_element_by_css_selector('.btn.btn-action.btn-lg.btn-block.loginbtn').click()
```

features/tutorial.feature

```
Feature: showing off behave

  Background: user is lead to the login page
    Given user is lead to the login page

  Scenario: login invalid
    When I log in
```

My directory structure is:

```
path = /Users/fran/PycharmProjects/prueba1
path/features/tutorial.feature
path/features/__init__.py
path/features/lib/__init__.py
path/features/lib/pages/__init__.py
path/features/lib/pages/login_page.py
path/features/steps/__init__.py
path/features/steps/tutorial.py
```

Im getting this error

```
  File "steps/tutorial.py", line 10, in <module>
    from features.lib.pages.login_page import LoginPage
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'features'
```

If I import it as

```
from ..lib.pages.login_page import LoginPage
```

I get

```
  File "steps/tutorial.py", line 10, in <module>
    from ..lib.pages.login_page import LoginPage
KeyError: "'__name__' not in globals"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a Python search-path problem. The Python search-path needs to be set-up correctly to be able to import other Python modules (that are not installed).

PROBLEM: `path/` is not in your Python search-path (check: `sys.path` list-value in Python).

SOLUTIONS:

- Add the "path/" (as absolute-path) to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable before you run **behave**
- Add an "path/features/environemt.py" file that adds the "path/" to the Python search-path by using `sys.path`